# swift NotificationCenter и pushViewController

Tags: swift

В первом `viewcontroller` добавил наблюдателя, который меняет текст label

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updatePrice), name: Constants.NotificationUpdatePrice, object: nil)
...
@objc func updatePrice(){
    self.recomendLabel.text = "11111"
}
```

Во втором viewController показываю первый и посылаю наблюдателю "зеленый свет"

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller, animated: true)

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Constants.NotificationUpdatePrice, object: nil)
```

Проблема в том, что когда первый `viewcontroller` показывается текст у него остается не изменным, немного продебажив понял, что метод `updatePrice` вызывается раньше, чем, например, метод `viewWillAppear` и из-за этого текст возвращается на изначальный.

Как можно решить эту проблему ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меняйте текст не на константу "1111", а на переменную. Функция updatePrice() пусть так же меняет значение переменной.
Метод NotificationCenter.default.post вызывайте уже после показа первого UIViewController методом pushViewController (поменяйте строки местами).
В этом случае, метод viewWillAppear будет показывать правильные данные.

1-й UIViewController:

```
var text = "00000"
@objc func updatePrice() {
    text = "11111"
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.recomendLabel.text = text
}
```

2-й UIViewController:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Constants.NotificationUpdatePrice, object: nil)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller, animated: true)
```